# Flash BIOS on multiple computers over the network?

Tags: updates, bios

This might be a ridiculous question but is there a way to Upgrade the bios of multiple machines via the network?

-We have multiple Lenovo machines that require BIOS updates that we are doing manually.

-We use GhostCast to cast Windows images on our computers.

I've searched around and found people asking similar questions but no response.

Any possibilities or is this just not possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the BIOS and the company - I have no idea what options Lenovo provides.

Certain Dell business class (Optiplex/Lattitude/???) you can, using one of a couple different Dell-provided tools, ranging from a simple util that lets you spit out an .exe with updated code and settings (including password if required) that you can then push out using your favorite method, up to server-based monstrosities that wants a whole SQL server to itself. (But once it's working it scans network and reports what out there, compares to its internal repository, etc.)

It the comps support vPro or whatever Out of Band Management, and/or you can implement PXE booting, you could probably hack something together - depends on how many comps you're talking about, and again, how lenovo implements things.